# How can i disable sorting effect on serial number column due to sorting on other columns in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to have a fixed serial no column irrespective of sorting on other column. Currently when i'm sorting other columns serial no columns also get swapped thus jumbling the order of serial no column. How can i keep it static irrespective of sorting on other columns?

Answer (score 0):

Does your serial no. is just an incremental no. like 1,2,3...? If that is the case you can update the data of serial no. using increment then just call `redrawRows()`. If the serial no. is a random number or saved data just save it first in an array then update the data of serial no. based on the saved array. Used `onSortChanged()` to listen on the sort changed event.

Comment: yes. It's just an incremental number 1,2,3... But in react where do i call redrawRows() as react render method doesnt get called when i sort the columns.

Comment: I do not use React but I think this is what you need. 

`props.column.addEventListener('sortChanged', this.onSortChanged.bind(this));`

Look at this example. I get it on the ag-Grid documentation Header Components

https://plnkr.co/edit/gHJR3qALs2uJLWPE

You need to add an event listener for sort change then on the sort change method do the update of your data then call redrawRows()

Comment: `this.gridOptions.onSortChanged = event => {
    // Update Data
    this.gridApi.redrawRows();
};`

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-reference-overview/#events-via-the-gridoptions-property